# Catch links from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file txt, where there are severals lines... Some of these are links. My question is: How can I catch all this links and save them on another txt file? I'm a newbie.

I tried with this but it doesn't work:

```
filee = open("myfile.txt").readlines()
out_file = open("out.txt","w")
out_file.write("")
out_file.close()

for x in filee:
    if x.startswith("http"):
        out_file.write(x)
        print (x)
```

Comment: Side-note: Use [`with` statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) when dealing with files. It makes it impossible to accidentally omit a `close` call (no `close` call is necessary), and makes it easier to see when a resource can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write to a closed file. Just move the out_file.close() at the end of your code:

```
filee = open("myfile.txt").readlines()
out_file = open("out.txt","w")
out_file.write("")

for x in filee:
    if x.startswith("http"):
        out_file.write(x)
        print (x)
out_file.close()
```

Here a cleaner version:

```
# open the input file (with auto close)
with open("myfile.txt") as input_file:

    # open the output file (with auto close)
    with open("out.txt", "w") as output_file:

        # for each line of the file
        for line in input_file:

            # append the line to the output file if start with "http"
            if line.startswith("http"):
                output_file.write(line)
```

You can also combine the two with:

```
# open the input/output files (with auto close)
with open("myfile.txt") as input_file, open("out.txt", "w") as output_file:

    # for each line of the file
    for line in input_file:

        # append the line to the output file if start with "http"
        if line.startswith("http"):
            output_file.write(line)
```